# How to find the the child tag of a parent Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to figure out how to find the child tag of a parent tag because I am scraping a webpage has multiple classes by the same name and I am just trying to get the one that I need. I have looked in the docs and cant find information or cant understand the information about this.I hope someone can help me out with this alos at the same time helping the community. If this is a duplicate please inform me in the comments and I will close the question. Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://weather.com/en-IE/weather/tenday/l/e98742cdb581b2f4461e4f438badbfb0e16dc9e70ffbf4c8df1b0f7a4394f9f9")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"lxml")
parent = soup.find("span" class_= "DetailsSummary--extendedData--365A_"("details" , class_ = "Disclosure themeList--25Q0H"))
print(parent)
```

Hope someone can answer as soon as possible.

Comment: You can use ```parent.find(...)``` it will find all the elements under parent scope

Comment: @Just Me can you elaborate on your comment as I still do not understand what to do

Comment: Please, add your expected output and html-snippet (not image) you try to find, improving your question.

Comment: @GCIreland ```parent.find(class_='example')``` will find class with name example which is a child of ```parent```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can use find parent then add .find on to that and put in your prematers